# Axios interceptor does not redirect browser in a React app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, axios

I have a Redux/React application with an OAuth2 proxy. When the proxy gives a 401 response, the user needs to be redirected to an authentication page. Here is the basic idea using `axios` and interceptors.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const axiosApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/proxy/api',
})

axiosApi.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  // Intercept successful response data
  return response
}, error => {
  if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
    // Redirect when not authenticated
    window.location.href = '/proxy/authorize'
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
})
```

This is what the Redux actions that consume the axiosApi look like:

```
export const fetchUsers = () => dispatch =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axiosApi.get(`users`)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersData(res.data))
        resolve(res)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      })
  })
```

The problem is that `window.location.href = '/proxy/authorize'` does not actually redirect the browser. Is this because react-router(V5) is used?

Comment: window.location.replace

Comment: I did try with `window.location.replace('proxy/authorize')` but that made no difference.

Comment: you need the full url and http/https

Comment: That does not seem to be the problem. Why would I need the full url anyways? Try to open a console and do `location.replace('/users/4038702/pandelis')`